# How to get size and subset of TFRecordDataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am playing with the deepmind-research/meshgraphnets code that can be found here: https://github.com/deepmind/deepmind-research/blob/master/meshgraphnets. The specific dataset I am working with is the `flag_simple` dataset and can be downloaded from this link: https://storage.googleapis.com/dm-meshgraphnets/flag_simple/train.tfrecord. If you don't trust that link, you can look in the `download_dataset.sh` file to see how they download the data.

I am trying to reduce the size of the training dataset when it is loaded so the model isn't training on the full dataset. I have made an attempt at doing this by modifying the `load_dataset` function in the `dataset.py` file. The modified function can be seen below:

```
def load_dataset(path, split, size=1.0):
  """Load dataset."""
  with open(os.path.join(path, 'meta.json'), 'r') as fp:
    meta = json.loads(fp.read())
  ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(os.path.join(path, split+'.tfrecord'))
  
  # Code to reduce the size of the dataset
  if size < 1.0:
      num_samples = get_size(ds) * size
      ds = ds.take(num_samples)  

  ds = ds.map(functools.partial(_parse, meta=meta), num_parallel_calls=8)
  ds = ds.prefetch(1)
  return
```

The main issue I am having is that the `get_size` function I have written is not working. I have tried using an iterator approach and a reduce approach. The iterator approach takes an insanely long time to run, and eventually just kills the program once it has ran for so long. The reduce approach returns 0, so I am not sure how to go about getting the size of the original dataset.

**Iterator Approach:**
This one takes too long and kills the program before finishing.

```
def get_size(ds):
    iterator = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
    count = 0
    try:
        while True:
            element = iterator.get_next()
            count += 1
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        pass
    
    return count
```

**Reduce Approach:**
This one returns 0: `Tensor("ReduceDataset:0, shape=(), dtype=int32)`

```
def get_size(ds):
    return ds.reduce(0, lambda x, _: x + 1)
```

For some more information, the Tensorflow version has to be version 1.x.